# error al crear un proyecto simple en spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

tengo un error que al crear un proyecto simple con spring boot 
tengo un controlador , un servicio  y una vista
el error que me tira es este

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-05-29 16:34:49.209
>   ERROR 10176 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field servicio in com.jose.controllers.HomeController required a bean
>   of type 'com.jose.services.HomeService' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.jose.services.HomeService' in
>   your configuration.

```
package com.jose.controllers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.jose.services.HomeService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private  HomeService servicio;



    @RequestMapping("lista")
    public  String lista() {
        return servicio.lista();
    }

    @RequestMapping("eliminar")
    public String eliminar() {
        return "eliminar";
    }
}
```

el servicio

```
package com.jose.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HomeService {

    public String lista() {
        return "lista";
    }


    public String eliminar() {
        return "eliminar";
    }
}
```

y las vistas

> en los templates que son eliminar.html , eliminar.html

Comment: descubri que me funciona si pongo los controladores y los servicios todos junto en el mismo paquete. Por que sucede eso hay alguna configuracion que tenga que escribir?

Comment: El error indica que Spring no es capaz de encontrar tu clase HomeService. Es un problema de configuración, pero si no añades más detalles es complicado ver el origen exacto. Mi apuesta es que Spring no está buscando en el paquete `com.jose.service` porque no se le ha indicado. ¿Cuál es el paquete donde está la clase que inicia todo? ¿Cómo es el fichero de configuración?

Answer (score 1):

Un controlador puede tener inyectados servicios. Los servicios son interfaces y las implementaciones de esas interfaces sí tendrán la anotación @Service y el código para hacer cada operación que tu necesitas, es decir, la lógica del negocio. En ocasiones las clases que implementan @Service utilizan repositorios que se encargan de manejar los entities y toda la capa de persistencia.

Tal vez después de leer el siguiente post y realizar el ejemplo puedas tener un poco más claro los conceptos que te menciono.

https://codigochido.com/post/2018-07-09-acervo-api/

También te recomiendo leer sobre DDD o Clean ya que algunos conceptos teoricos veo que no te quedan claros y por eso el programarlos te resulta complicado.

Saludos cordiales.